# My subdomain keeps redirecting to my main domain

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, subdomain, virtualhost

I am sure this must have been asked multiple times already, I researched it for like a day but still couldn't figure it out.

I have a domain - **domain.com** and now I want to add a subdomain - **test.domain.com** for it. I have created a virtual host file and DNS A record - **test.domain.com** pointing to my server IP. But then whenever I try to access my **test.domain.com**, it keeps redirecting to **domain.com**. My Apache2 virtual host files are configured as follow

**domain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/domain.com">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**domain.com-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName domain.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.domain.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**test.domain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.domain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.test.domain.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.domain.com
        RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/test.domain.com">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I have enabled the conf files with the command a2ensite and restarted apache (and desperately my server droplet) multiple times already but still couldn't get it to work. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.6.

Any advise would be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A minimalistic example would be along these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.example.com
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In this example you declare a virtualhost for `test.example.com` and also `www.test.example.com`.

*Note that I am using example.com here instead of domain.com because of [posting restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke) active on this website.*

The RewriteRule directives in your subdomain don't seem to be right, at least syntactically. They may be causing the redirection problem.
So I would remove them and take care of redirects later. Start with a simple configuration, validate it and expand with more rules later.

Hint: you could use **curl** (from the command line on your server if not available on your PC) to test like this:`curl -L --head "http://example.com"`.
Test the main domain name, then subdomain in both http and https. There is an option in Curl to ignore SSL/TLS errors if you encounter any.

See what happens and pay attention to the redirects if any (status code 301/302).

I prefer to use Curl for testing because the browser cache can play tricks on you.